# Create using for own helper? like Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I was wondering, is it possible to create your own helper definition, with a using? such as the following which creates a form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm(params)) 
{
}
```

I'd like to make my own helper like that. So a simple example I'd like to do

```
using(Tablehelper.Begintable(id)
{
    <th>content etc<th>
}
```

which will output in my view

```
<table>
  <th>content etc<th>
</table>
```

Is this possible? if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sure, it's possible:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    private class Table : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TextWriter _writer;
        public Table(TextWriter writer)
        {
            _writer = writer;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _writer.Write("</table>");
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable BeginTable(this HtmlHelper html, string id)
    {
        var writer = html.ViewContext.Writer;
        writer.Write(string.Format("<table id=\"{0}\">", id));
        return new Table(writer);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@using(Html.BeginTable("abc"))
{
    @:<th>content etc<th>
}
```

will yield:

```
<table id="abc">
    <th>content etc<th>
</table>
```

I'd also recommend you reading about [Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Since you did this in a class, I assume it isnt possible with a regular @helper Method()? 
Also, where do I place this? I tried just putting it in my app_code folder with the rest of the helpers, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: @RonSijm, you could place this class in a `HtmlExtensions.cs` file inside an `Extensions` folder for example. Just make sure that you bring the namespace into which this class is defined into scope in your view so that you can have access to the extension method: `@using AppName.Extensions`.

Comment: thanks, that seems to work. Too bad it does not work just putting the using in _layout.cshtml though.

Comment: @RonSijm, you could add the namespace to the `<namespaces>` section of `~/Views/web.config` file (**not** `~/web.config`). This way the helper will be universally available within your application. Or simply change its namespace to `System.Web.Mvc.Html` which is where all standard helpers are defined.

Comment: One thing to note... you should override the ToString() returning empty in the Table class... if not you will see the a text like YourDomain.HtmlExtensions.Table a long with the table.

Comment: @Romias I noticed this happening when I neglected to include the "using" in my razor templates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is; however, to use `Tablehelper.*` you would need to subclass the base-view and add a `Tablehelper` property. Probably easier, though, is to add an extension method to `HtmlHelper`:

```
public static SomeType BeginTable(this HtmlHelper html, string id) {
    ...
}
```

which will allow you to write:

```
using (Html.BeginTable(id))
{
    ...
}
```

but this will in turn require various other bits of plumbing (to start the element at `BeginTable`, and end it in `Dispose()` on the returned value).