# C# ASP.net EditorTemplate - get name of the used model property

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a razor view where I call this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Code)
```

Then I have an EditorTemplate view which is rendered then, it looks like this:

```
@model string
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m)
```

And I get this output:

```
<input id="Code" name="Code" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Everything fine.

But now I just want to get the property name `Code` inside the EditorTemplate view, not the whole input string. The `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m)` method is able to get it from the model object somehow and put it into the input field but how can I do this?

(And no, I don't want to parse it from the input field string... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m)` seems kind of weird... but anyway:

[HiddenFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor.aspx) uses `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` so you could make your own function to only return the name:

```
 public static class GenericHelper<T>
 {
     public static String GetPropertyName<TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> propertyId)
     {
         var operant = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)propertyId.Body).Operand;
         return operant.Member.Name;
     }
}
```

And create a helper to use that inside your view, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928532/create-using-for-own-helper-like-html-beginform)

Comment: I don't use the @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m) really, I just wanted to show that the helper is able to get what I want. Thanks for the answer! I have to dig a little bit in these Expressions, I'm not very familiar with it.