# How can I get the property name in my MVC3 custom Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an enumeration in my project and I've created a custom editor template for this enumeration. So, now any model I have with a property with a type of this enumeration, will render a drop down.

This works great, but I would like to name my select element of my dropdown with the name of the property.  Here is my Razor code for my editor template.

```
    @model ItemEnumerations.ItemType

    <select id="PropertyNameHere" name="PropertyNameHere">
    @foreach (ItemEnumerations.ItemType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ItemEnumerations.ItemType))) {
        <option value="@value" @(Model == @value ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>@value.ToString()</option>           
    }
    </select>
```

So, where I have 'PropertyNameHere' for the select elements id and name attributes, I would like to have the name of the property of my model.  Here is an example:

My Model:

```
    public class MyModel{
        public int ItemID {get;set;}
        public string ItemName {get;set;}
        public ItemEnumerations.ItemType MyItemType {get;set;}
    }
```

My View Code:

```
@model MyModel

@Html.LabelFor(m => model.ItemID)
@Html.DisplayForm(m => model.ItemID)

@Html.LabelFor(m => model.ItemName)
@Html.EditorFor(m => model.ItemName)

@Html.LabelFor(m => model.MyItemType )
@Html.EditorFor(m => model.MyItemType )
```

I would like my select element to have a name and id of 'MyItemType'.

Comment: Maybe a better solution would be to extend the DropDownFor method to handle my enumeration?

Comment: Try this... http://blog.nathan-taylor.net/2012/10/aspnet-mvc-get-field-name-and-id-for.html

Comment: Glad you asked this question because that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I found the answer in a book I have here.  Actually, it got me close, but I then could google the rest based on what I found.

Here is what I needed to add to my editor template.

```
@{var fieldName = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;}
<select id="@fieldName" name="@fieldName">
```

Comment: tks Jeff, after this i've found the method GetFullHtmlFieldName() ...  ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("field")

Comment: If you use the default template for the editor, you could also get the name via `ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName`. However, using the solution you have proposed works using the default template or specifiying a template name (i.e. `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ItemName, "templatename")`).

Comment: If for some reason someone needs the data annotated display name when they stumble on this question (I did) they can use @ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName

Answer (score 29):

For future reference (old question), I found this: System.Web.Mvc.Html.NameExtensions.

Using those, you can do something like

```
<input type=text" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.MyProperty)">
```

And you'll get

```
<input type=text" name="MyProperty">
```

There are several other related helpers in this extension class. This method does more than just get the property name, though. For example, you could use m.MyProperty.MySubProperty and you'd get a valid HTML name for posting.

Comment: Good to know. It does not answer the question though, since you still need to know the name `MyProperty` to be able to use it. But if you call `EditorFor(m => m.MyProperty)` and within the Editor template you want to find out that the name it was called for was `MyProperty` this does not help.

Comment: This solved my problem of getting names of  nested properties.

Answer (score 4):

How about the following template:

```
@model ItemEnumerations.ItemType
@{
    var values = 
        from value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ItemType)).Cast<ItemType>()
        select new { ID = (int)value, Name = value.ToString() };
    var list = new SelectList(values , "ID", "Name", (int)Model);
}
@Html.DropDownList("", list)
```

This way you don't need to manually render `<select>` and `<option>` tags and you are reusing the existing `DropDownList` helper.

Comment: This worked with my code (see my answer to this question), but I'm abandoning that for your solution.  I like using the existing helper. Once again, Thanks Darin.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the property name in the editor template via

```
@{
   string name = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper to use that inside your view, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928532/create-using-for-own-helper-like-html-beginform)

And you can use this piece of code to get the name.

```
 public static class GenericHelper<T>
 {
     public static String GetPropertyName<TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> propertyId)
     {
         var operant = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)propertyId.Body).Operand;
         return operant.Member.Name;
     }
}
```

I assume the default helpers do the same, such as [HiddenFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor.aspx), as they also use `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`

Comment: I was hoping to get the property name via some metadata.  I'd like to make this as generic as possible.

Comment: Using Expression<> does keep it generic right?
In your view you'd use @Http.YourHelper(m => model.ItemID) where your helper returns GetPropertyName from the code snippet

Comment: see my comment to @Todd, applies here, too.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the accepted answer, `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` gives you the property name inside an EditorTemplate.

I think it is worth saying that you can use an empty string inside the HtmlHelper functions if your goal is to generate an input/select. It will use the model's property name.

```
@Html.TextBox("", theValue, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownList("", new List<SelectListItem>(), theValue, new { @class = "form-control" })
```