# Restrict Date Range in jQuery DatePicker in MVC3 Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am currently working on jQuery date picker where I want to restrict the user to select the date from 1st of every month to 28th of every month.

The remaining dates after 28th would not be selectable, I want to achieve this. Is there any way possible I can do that.

Like for a thought, I was trying to put data annotation on the date variable of Model class but then don't know how to do that. Other option that I believe would look more sophisticated is to make the unwanted dates not selectable while the date picker appears.

Comment: you can you mindate parameter for the same

Answer (score 2):

Lets first go over what the html/js will look like. So, use the beforeShowDay property of the datepicker to limit the days that can be shown

javascript

```
$('#date').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDate() <= 28,""];}
})
```

html

```
<input id="date" type="text" value="">
```

Here is a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dWaLq/ that demonstrates this. and here is the relevant jquery ui docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

Theres a few ways to connect the javascript/html to your view.

One option is to use the UIHintAttribute to specify the viewmodel to use with your date property

in your viewmodel

```
 [UIHint("LimitedDate")]
 public DateTime date {get;set;}
```

and in your view

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.date)
```

and you would have a custom view LimitedDate.cshtml  in your Views >  Shared > Editor folder

```
@model DateTime

@{var fieldName = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;}
<input id="@fieldName" name="@fieldName" type="text" value="@Model.ToString('d')">

<script>
  $('#' + '@fieldname').datepicker({
     beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDate() <= 28,""];}
  })
</script>
```

you can look at [How can I get the property name in my MVC3 custom Editor Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186012/how-can-i-get-the-property-name-in-my-mvc3-custom-editor-template) for more support on getting the property name into the editor.