# Creating Html helper like BeginForm in Nancy with Razor

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

We're using a self hosted Nancy server where I'm using the Razor viewengine for serving up web views.
I'm looking into creating custom HtmlHelpers and have been able to get simple examples working. But one thing I'd like to do is a helper that works like BeginForm(), that you can use with a using statement in the markup to create output both at the beginning and the end of the using-block.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <some html here>
}
```

All examples I've found are based on Asp.Net MVC, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7928566/1128038
It doesn't seem to work the same way in the Nancy implementation.
Is this at all possible to do?

Comment: Did you work out how to do this? I'd love to know as well.

Comment: @BenDaniel No, I guess you need to use the Microsoft implementation to be able to to it.

Answer (score 3):

Try use extension method like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static BeginFormObject BeginForm(this HtmlHelpers helpers, NancyRazorViewBase view)
    {
        return new BeginFormObject("<form method=\"post\">", view);
    }

    public class BeginFormObject : IDisposable
    {
        private NancyRazorViewBase view;
        public BeginFormObject(string markup, NancyRazorViewBase view)
        {
            this.view = view;
            view.WriteLiteral(markup);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            view.WriteLiteral("</form>");
        }
    }
}
```

This allows to use following syntax in razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(this))
{
....other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This https://gist.github.com/thecodejunkie/6298564 should get your started.

Comment: Yes, I've been able to do that kind of extensions. I've clarified the question to better explain what I would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Piotr answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23236793/5181092),
I just created an repository in GitHub for testing this.

It's a simple solution that Mix Self hosting and Razor.

Check if it is what you searching:
[NancySelfHostRazorTest](https://github.com/RafaelDelboni/NancySelfHostRazorTest)

Good luck.